Elastic Beanstalk is not scaling as expected on Request Count metric
I want my Elastic beanstalk to scale on request count but after running some testing script it donot scale as expected also my load balancer is not responding real time traffic. It takes long to reflect number. My current scaling configurations of beanstalk are:

My application was on EC2 instances before and and 2 instances were able to manage upto 9k traffic.
I have tried adding two instances as desired capacity, I also modified breach duration to 1 min and scaling threshold up and down but still same. I noticed that my ALB is not reflecting changes real time, it takes time to reflect even I have configured cloud watch metric interval to 1 minute. The results are:

The EC2 get loaded - and CPU get 92%
I see Gateway timout after some time but it fixes when i cancel the testing workflow
The load balancer takes time to reflect, while i cancelled the testing workflow the traffic was 669 but after 2-3 mins of cancelling workflow the traffic touched 4.9k.

Note: My testing load script has no issues it is designed to provide upto 4k traffic
The script is written below:
config:
  environments:
    staging:
      target: "********.com"
      http:
        timeout: 300
      phases:
        - duration: 20
          arrivalCount: 20
          name: Warm up phase
        - duration: 120
          arrivalRate: 25
          name: Step 1 # ~3k requests in 2 minutes
        - duration: 180
          name: Wait after Step 1 # 3 minutes
        - duration: 60
          arrivalRate: 50
          name: Step 2 # ~3k requests in 1 minute
        - duration: 300
          name: Wait after Step 2 # 5 minutes
        - duration: 30
          arrivalRate: 133
          name: Step 3 # ~4k requests in 30 seconds
        - duration: 360
          name: Wait after Step 3 # 6 minutes
        - duration: 300
          name: Wait for 5 minutes
        - duration: 120
          arrivalRate: 33
          name: Decrease to 4000 phase

scenarios:
  - name: Spike for Backend
    flow:
      - get:
          url: "/"

